# Filesystems content of docker container on host

Tags: docker, host

I've read quite a lot about how docker works using cgroups and namespaces. If that's correct the *host* should be able to see all the processes and filesystem tree that is used by the docker container. However I seem to be unable to figure it out.

Could someone show it with docker v1.12.6 and a running "nginx" container?

Optional: Is it possible to still access the files of already exited containers the same way?

PS, GraphDriver looks like this:

```
"GraphDriver" : {
  "Name" : "aufs",
  "Data" : null
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy files from docker using docker cp command then you can access it.That will be simplest way to access files from exited container,too.

Comment: I can use this as a workaround, but it's not a solution. If I `docker cp` a file that doesn't exist it will error that it can't `lstat` the file with the full host path. That works fine as a workaround, but I'd still like to figure out the real version. Anyways, thumbs up because with that I can continue coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When running on the *host* that the docker daemon runs on, you can run (as root);

Start an nginx container

```
docker run -d nginx
```

View all processes that are running, hierarchically

```
ps auxf
```

which shows all processes, including the nginx container you just started;

```
root      3810  0.9  3.2 387460 67308 ?        Ssl  11:31   0:12 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
root      3819  0.1  0.6 291624 14028 ?        Ssl  11:31   0:01  \_ docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
root      4241  0.0  0.3 143872  6652 ?        Sl   11:49   0:00      \_ docker-containerd-shim 1d3a6c65ac59e61c165d1f0119915a43e4d0387fd8432723f16b1ef2aa966522 /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/1d3a6c65ac59e61c165d1f0119915a43e4d0387fd8432723f16b1ef2aa966522 docker-runc
root      4277  0.0  0.2  31872  5280 ?        Ss   11:49   0:00          \_ nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
syslog    4304  0.0  0.1  32260  2904 ?        S    11:49   0:00              \_ nginx: worker process
```

**container's filesystem**

The storage location for container filesystems depend on the storage driver you're using. In your case the layers of images, and (writable) layers of containers are kept in `/var/lib/docker/aufs`. However, those files should not be messed with directly. You can use

- `docker cp` to copy files from/to a container (even an exited container)
- `docker export` to export the container's filesystem to a tar archive
- `docker commit` a container to an image

Comment: These are the processes, but not the files. For instance the ´/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`that the `nginx`process uses inside the container.

Comment: Sorry, was confused by your question "host should be able to see all the _processes_ and filesystem tree". Added more information about the container's filesystem location. Note that _volumes_ are not stored on the container's filesystem, but in a separate location